# Replace part of a string Shell Scripting

Tags: shell

I have lines and want to do sed operation, on string which comes after it has read '|'character three times. How can I do this in Shell Script?

**Input:** `aaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|hello`

**Desired Ouput:** `aaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|hel`

This is be done on hello which is after three '|'

-> `sed 's/({.3}).*/\1/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what you want to do with the last field to transform "hello" into "hel". Here's one way:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^|]+\|){3})(...).*/\1\3/' file
```

- `([^|]+\|)` denotes a pipe delimited field (with the pipe)
- `(([^|]+\|){3})` denotes three such fields

  - requires sed's `-r` option
  - on OSX or BSD-ish implementations of sed, use `-E` instead)
- I capture the next three characters with `(...)`
- then replace all with the first and third set of capturing parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) command instead of `sed`:

```
$ echo "aaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|hello" | cut -d '|' -f 4
hello
```

Comment: I wish to make changes in the file itself.